# Loop on field change C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write some code to loop through a data range and add new documents to SAP based on a query input. I need the values to be added to the documents based on the supplier field and when the supplier changes create a new document. Currently I am only able to loop through adding items to the document and rather than moving to the next supplier it just loops the items again. I'm pretty new to C# so looping is pretty new to me but hoping someone can help?

```cs
int recordCount = oRecordset.RecordCount;

string Supplier = oRecordset.Fields.Item(1).Value.ToString();
string Item = oRecordset.Fields.Item(0).Value.ToString();
Qty = Convert.ToInt32(oRecordset.Fields.Item(3).Value.ToString());

if(recordCount>0)
    application.MessageBox("Adding PQ");

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
{
    for(int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++)
    {
        OPQT.CardCode = Supplier ;
        OPQT.DocDate = DateTime.Now;
        OPQT.DocDueDate = DateTime.Now;
        OPQT.RequriedDate = DateTime.Now;
        OPQT.Lines.ItemCode = Item;
        OPQT.Lines.RequiredQuantity = Qty;
        OPQT.Lines.Add();
        oRecordset.MoveNext();
    }
   OPQT.Add();
   application.MessageBox("PQ Added");
}
```

Comment: what type is `oRecordset`?

Comment: There is nothing inside you loop that retrieves anything from the `oRecordset` based on the index `i` so, your loop will repeat the same code, with the same values, `recordCount` times.

Comment: `oRecordset` is an SQL query, Thats the issue i'm not sure how to retrieve data from `oRecordset` using the index

Comment: I am not aware of the SQL Query type, is it your own definition? It is not something familiar like [`SqlDataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) or [`DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0).

Comment: It uses `oRecordset.DoQuery` it appears to be similar to sqlDataReader

Comment: oRecordset could be an ADODB.Recordset, but we definitely need some more information to be able to answer this.

Comment: Oh I see, apologies. I'm still learning. SAPbobsCOM.Recordset is what I think you're looking for

Comment: @PalleDue, looks right but retro, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-properties-methods-and-events?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This is the remainder of the code used. `SAPbobsCOM.Documents OPQT = (SAPbobsCOM.Documents)company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oPurchaseQuotations);

SAPbobsCOM.Recordset oRecordset = (SAPbobsCOM.Recordset)company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);

int Qty = -1;

oRecordset.DoQuery("SELECT T0.\"ItemCode\", T0.\"CardCode\", '10' AS \"Qty\" FROM OSCN T0 INNER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.\"CardCode\" = T1.\"CardCode\" WHERE T1.\"CardType\" ='S'");`

Comment: You'd be better of starting here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#examples

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better of starting to learn with [`SqlDataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#examples), IMO.

Adapting to your business case you'd get something like this, this is not working code, I don't have enough info for that. However this should help you progress in the right direction.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=...";
        ReadOData( connectionString);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<OPQT> ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
    {
        string queryString =
            @"
SELECT
            T0.[ItemCode],
            T0.[CardCode],
            '10' [Qty]
    FROM
            [OSCN] T0
        JOIN
            [OCRD] T1
                ON T0.[CardCode] = T1.[CardCode]
    WHERE
            T1.[CardType] ='S'";

        using (SqlConnection connection =
                   new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                // Call Read before accessing data.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   yield return ReadSingleRow((IDataRecord)reader);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Call Close when done reading.
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static OPQT ReadSingleRow(IDataRecord dataRecord)
    {
        return new OPQT
        {
            Lines.ItemCode = dataRecord[0],
            CardCode = dataRecord[1],
            Lines.RequiredQuantity = dataRecord[2]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not sure if i will be able to adapt this for my needs. The code runs directly in our SAP software using a 3rd party addon to run the C# code so no connection needs to be established as it is already connected to our database.
The Query pulls out the below data so for each supplier in the list it needs to add the itemcode and qty fields and then start a new loop when the supplier changes.

ItemCode Supplier Qty
LKIOJ2135 Supplier1 100
LKIOJ2558 Supplier1 125
LKIOJ2135 Supplier2 100
LKIOJ2558 Supplier2 125
LKIOJ2135 Supplier3 100
LKIOJ2558 Supplier3 125

Comment: @MattW ah, so essentially SAP allows you to write a script in C#. I guess this is a mutation/evolution of their a legacy offering supporting scripts in VBA/VBScript, hence the very old ADODB objects being supplied. I often wonder what it is that makes SAP so popular for large organisations.

Comment: Correct and then it can be run directly through SAP. I'm currently looking at creating a temporary grid that can then be used as a data table which I can read the data from and then iterate through the supplier column adding new documents for each new supplier. I've managed to create a datatable using the query and can view the data but reading from it is a different story.